# "Opened exclusively be another user" when reading data from CSV by C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledbconnection, asp.net-4.5

I am running the code below in asp.net 4.5 solution and it gives me the error:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''.  It is
>   already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to
>   view its data.

The code follows:

```
private static string FileConnectionString(string filePath)
{
    return string.Format(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataFileCSV"].ToString(), filePath);
}
```

---

```
string DataUploadFolder = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataFileUploadFolder"].ToString();
string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(DataUploadFolder);

OleDbConnection fileConnection = new OleDbConnection(FileConnectionString(filePath));
try
{
    fileConnection.Open();
    string columnList = "Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5";
    DataTable fileDataTable = new DataTable();
    OleDbCommand command =  new OleDbCommand(string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM [{1}]",                                                                   
                                             columnList,
                                             FileUploadControl.FileName), 
                                fileConnection);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
    da.Fill(fileDataTable); //Exception occurs here !!
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
finally
{
    fileConnection.Close();
}
```

**Web.config:**

```
 <add key="DataFileCSV" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited';" />
```

Please note that the CSV file is not open anywhere. No file is open actually, only Visual Studio is open. I can open the file, change and save it as well. "Everyone" has "full control" permission on the file.

I can't see why the error is happening, could not find a way to fix it. Seen many pages with this error but no solution worked so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: In aspx, I use: `<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server" Width="400px" />`

Comment: If your process runs and fails the process may keep a lock on the file itself.  When it starts up again it shows the lock from the last time the file was run.  Either on failure, or maybe your process is not closing/dropping the connection to the file properly

Comment: "When it starts up again it shows the lock from the last time the file was run." Where does it show?

Comment: I have dealt with this issue in the past by copying the file to a temp location and opening that one.  If you change the name during the copy (append a time stamp, etc.) you can be assured that the file you try to open is always going to be unique and unlocked.

Comment: @techturtle I've tried it, copied it to another location, changed its name, created a dummy file in another temp location... nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consuming a day on this issue, I finally found a solution.

There are two steps needed to be followed:

1- By using OleDBConnection, it turned out you cannot read from the original file since as soon as the fileconnection is opened, it starts using the uploaded file. This is pushing us to copy the file to another temporary location. So add check line to the code.

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(filePath + fileName); //This is the line
OleDbConnection fileConnection = new OleDbConnection(FileConnectionString(filePath, fileName));
fileConnection.Open();
```

What it is doing that, I am uploading a file from my desktop to read the data, but the application copies it to another location first and read the data from the copy instead the original one.

2- The temporary location (folder) should have NETWORK SERVICE as a user. Go to the folder settings -> Security -> Add User -> Add NETWORK SERVICE with read-write rights.

Then, you will be good to go. Thanks @Bran and @techturtle for inspiring me in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Your Problem propably comes down to poor exception handling. Right in the example code you swallow exceptions, do not log their content and go on after fatal ones. Either of those is a fatal mistake of exception handling. And I asume the rest of your code has similar issues.

These kinds of expcetions usually come from not properly closing FileHandles. Wich does directly tie into exception handling. So I can only link these two articles as I did often before and hope you find a solution to your problem following their adice:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET